# Как проверить строку на пустоту

Tags: javascript, строки

Какой функцией можно проверить строку на пустоту?

Comment: Нужна функция на проверку пустой строки

Comment: какая строка является пустой?

Comment: @Grundy у которой жизнь не насыщена, она не катается на лыжах, не общается с друзьями, не увлекается ни чем, не читает, нет домашнего питомца, вся такая жизнь у неё пустая при пустая)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = prompt("test", "");
console.log(Boolean(test) + (Boolean(test) ? ' - ne pusto' : ' - pusto'));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 12):

```js
var test = "   ";
var test2 = " ыва ыва   ";

console.log(isEmpty(test));
console.log(isEmpty(test2));
 

function isEmpty(str) {
  if (str.trim() == '') 
    return true;
    
  return false;
}
```

Comment: А вариант с `test2.length` не оч?

Comment: @EugenEray угадай, что выдаст код `var test = "   "; console.log(test.length);` (в переменной три пробела)

Comment: Ну в теории пробел это тоже символ.

Comment: @EugenEray мои поздравления его с этим %)

Answer (score 7):

Работает как с `undefined`, так и с `null`:

```js
var str = '  ';

if (str != null && typeof str !== "undefined") {
   str = str.trim();
}

if (!str) { 
   console.log("Пусто");
}
```

Comment: неверно! при `var str = "   ";` (три пробела) не сработает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, вы правы, обновил ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Mr.Edinorozhok отметьте ответ как лучший, если помогло.

Comment: @phen0men вот поэтому проще сделать один `trim` и сравнить на пустоту  ;-)

Comment: кстати вот эта конструкция `str != null && typeof str !== undefined`  зачем?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос был в проверке строки на пустоту. Что, если в программе есть какое-то условие, которое преобразует строку в `null`, а не просто `' '`? Вот я об этом подумал и решил, что нужно сделать проверку и на это.

Comment: @phen0men Вместо этого можно просто `if(str)`

Comment: `typeof str !== undefined` - заведомо истинное условие. Кавычки пропустил. И вообще, что-то сомнительная полезность тут.