# Как проверить пустая ли строка ? (Обязательно через switch case)

Tags: javascript, switch

```
const numOrStr = prompt('input number or string');
console.log(numOrStr);

let result;

switch (numOrStr) {
    case null:
        result = 'ви скасували';
        break;
    case  ... :
        result = 'empty string';
        break;
    case !isNaN(numOrStr) || numOrStr:
        result = 'number is Ba_NAN';
        break;
    default:
        result = 'ok';
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: [Как проверить строку на пустоту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665535)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить строку на пустоту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665535/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 2):

> Как проверить пустая ли строка ? (Обязательно через switch case)

Как-то так...

```js
const str = ''

switch (str) {
    case '':
        console.log('Пустая строка')
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Пр...')
}
```